# Does a pregnant female body treat the fetus based on gender?

Tags: human-biology, human-anatomy, pregnancy

I have seen on a [youtube video](http://youtu.be/5Tg_3OVizrA?t=2m15s) that the female body produces antigenes and antibodies when she is pregnant with a boy. But this behaviour is not produced when she is pregnant with a girl. These means that the more antigenes she produces, the more femminin the next child will be. More antigenes are produced when she is pregnant with a boy.

1. Is this correct? if yes, then why does the female body produce antibodies and antigenes when the fetus is a boy and not a girl?
2. What other pregnancy actions or behaviours are gender based?

Comment: Can you link your source? Otherwise I would consider higly unlikely.

Comment: http://youtu.be/5Tg_3OVizrA?t=2m15s

Comment: Hmm, I always have my problems with the "scientists have found out" phrase when not linking to the actual publication, but I will have a look into it.

Comment: I haven't found any articles besides the formation of antibodies against the "Rhesus"-antigen which happens when the mother is Rh- and the baby is Rh+. This is not restricted to male babies but happens against both sexes. Besides this, it doesn't really make sense for the body to react in this way. The mechanism of [immunologic tolerance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immune_tolerance#Fetal_development) prevents the mother from launching an immune reaction against the fetus.

Comment: @user2360 If you don't get an answer here you may then want to ask your question on [skeptics.SE](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/). It is a SE website that deals with questions of the kind "is this claim (source) true?" question.